# Configure Apache to route http to https on a different server

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I need to route an "http" on one "serverA" to an https "serverB". The https is self-signed and so i do not require verification.
I have been able to get it to work with nginx with config below on serverA;

```
    upstream site_ssl {
            server serverB_IP:7061;
    }

    server {
            listen 7061 ;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;


            location /Notification {
                    proxy_ssl_verify              off;
                    proxy_pass https://site_ssl;
            }
    }
```

I need to recreate this in Apache web server, and i have tried different suggestions but my current version looks like below;

```
<VirtualHost *:7061>
    ServerName serverA
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire Off
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /Notification https://serverB:7061
    ProxyPassReverse /Notification  https://serverB:7061
</VirtualHost>
```

The Apache setup timesout or responds with "Unable to get response". The nginx setup is flawless. I need the Apache setup translated so it works just like the nginx

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the *nginx* configuration, I understand that *serverB* is listening on *443/tcp*. So I would see instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:7061>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    ServerName serverA
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire Off
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /Notification https://serverB
    ProxyPassReverse /Notification  https://serverB
</VirtualHost>
```

**edit:** I think that you also need *SSLEngine* and *SSLCertificate{File,KeyFile}* settings in order to terminate the *SSL* connection .

Comment: ServerB ssl port is 7061 not 443, the solution did not work. tnx

Comment: Could you check the loaded modules with `a2query -m | grep proxy` and ensure that you also enabled *proxy_http* ?